# VAO VBO рисование геометрии

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

Совсем недавно начал работать с опенгл. На данный момент пытаюсь реализовать простейший "батчер". В приведенном коде - минимальная последовательность действий для отрисовки геометрии. Застрял на этапе заполнения VBO и VAO корректными данными.

У меня на экране НЕ рисуется затекстуренный, цветной квад.

Приведенный код не взят просто из головы, а написан опираясь на несколько примеров.
Проблем не возникало пока  Vertex2D состоял только из 1 атрибута (х, у).
Потом я добавил текстурные координаты и цвет. Вот тут моя голова и пошла кругом.

Подскажите по поводу правильного способа достичь этого в моем примере.

1) glVertexAttribPointer или glVertexPointer? и в какой момент? (VAO state .. ?)

2) Какие glEnable...() функции нужно использовать? и в какой момент? (VAO state .. ?)

Если я делаю что то совсем неправильное или суть вопроса не ясна, пожалуйста дайте знать!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

namespace test
{
    public struct Vertex
    {
        float X, Y;
        float U, V;
        float R, G, B, A;

        public Vertex(float x, float y, float u, float v, float r, float g, float b, float a)
        {
            X = x; Y = y;
            U = u; V = v;
            R = r; G = g; B = b; A = a;
        }
        public const int Stride = 32;
    }

    class VboRenderer
    {
        private int VaoId;
        private int VboId;

        private Vertex[] Vertices;

        public VboRenderer()
        {
            InitializeVBO();
        }

        private void InitializeVBO()
        {
            //Simple quad from 2 tris in CW
            Vertices = new Vertex[6]
            {
                new Vertex(0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255),
                new Vertex(1, 0, 1, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255),
                new Vertex(0, 1, 0, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255),

                new Vertex(0, 1, 0, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255),
                new Vertex(1, 0, 1, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255),
                new Vertex(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255),
            };

            //Ids
            GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VaoId);
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out VboId);

            //Generate a vao array
            GL.BindVertexArray(VaoId);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VboId);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 0));
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 2));
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 4));
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);

            //Generate a vbo buffer
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VboId);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(Vertices.Length * Vertex.Stride),
                Vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        public void RenderVBO(float x, float y, float size, float rot)
        {
            GL.PushMatrix();

            //Model-view
            Matrix4 transform = Matrix4.Identity;
            transform = Matrix4.Mult(transform, Matrix4.CreateScale((float)size, (float)size, 1.0f));
            transform = Matrix4.Mult(transform, Matrix4.CreateRotationZ((float)rot));
            transform = Matrix4.Mult(transform, Matrix4.CreateTranslation(x, y, 0.0f));
            GL.MultMatrix(ref transform);

            //Bindings
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, Main.texture.Handle);
            GL.BindVertexArray(VaoId);

            //Render
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 1);

            //Un bindings
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);

            GL.PopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opentk` не использовал, но не думаю что они уклонились от `opengl API` при реализации байндинга. Так что ответ дам опираясь на знания по `openGL API` если не возражаете.

Вопервых вот это

`GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 1);`

замените на

`GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6);`

так как вы рисуете квад 2-мя треугольниками который имеет каждый по 3 вершины, итого выходит 6 вершин, а вы почему то только 1 вершину указали.

Во вторых вот эта часть кода:

```
    //Ids
    GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VaoId);
    GL.GenBuffers(1, out VboId);

    //Generate a vao array
    GL.BindVertexArray(VaoId);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VboId);
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 0));
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 2));
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 4));
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    GL.BindVertexArray(0);

    //Generate a vbo buffer
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VboId);
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(Vertices.Length * Vertex.Stride),
        Vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
```

заполняйте `vbo` после вызова

`GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VboId);`

и абсолютно не зачем его потом делать `unbinding` строкой

`GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);` так как для активизации или сбрасывания всего состояния отрисовки как раз нужен `binding` и `unbinding` уже самого `vao`

вобщем вот исправленная часть этого кода:

```
    // Ids
    GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VaoId);
    GL.GenBuffers(1, out VboId);
    // Generate a vao array
    GL.BindVertexArray(VaoId);

       // Generate a vbo buffer
       GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VboId);
       GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(Vertices.Length * Vertex.Stride),
        Vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);           

       GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 0));
       GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 2));
       GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vertex.Stride, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * 4));  

       GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
       GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
       GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);         

    GL.BindVertexArray(0);
```

А текстуру нужно ещё передавать во фрагментный шейдер через `uniform` 
тоесть после строки

`GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, Main.texture.Handle);`

нужно ещё написать

`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation("texture"), 0)`

где `texture` определён во фрагментном шейдере как

`uniform sampler2D texture;

   void main() {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord);
   }`

удачи